# Filtering multiple areas in sunburst chart

Tags: filter

I have a sunburst chart with different filtering options. Like so:
[image]

The user will be able to choose multiple areas to filter on. But how do I make it clear to the user WHAT he has been filtering on?
[image]

The different selections have quite long names I’m afraid, which makes it more difficult. Each selection will also have a long “breadcrumb” of selections, like so:  Green 2; Yellow 3; Red 2.

I would love to have something like this:
[image]

To make it easy for the user to view his selected filters and also remove a filter

(There will be a legend that tells the user what each color mean)

Comment: I think your proposal isn't too bad, perhaps you can also add colours to the tags to make it easier to relate to the chart?

Comment: Thank you for input! The problem is that de selected section eg. Iowa has some kind of "history". Say that the green section is a status filtering, so the different sections has the value of "high", "medium" and "low" and let’s say the yellow section has the value of a number.
I’m afraid it won’t matter if I set the Iowa tag in some color since it is still missing important information, eg. Low>5>Iowa,

Answer (score 3):

How about something along these lines?

When a section is toggled on/off, a corresponding label is deselected in a list/legend.

Adding checkboxes (or making the labels themselves clickable) to the list could add an additional way to filter. Might be easier to scan down a list and toggle on/off your filters than only having the option to hunt for them on the chart. I would still keep the chart sections toggle able too.

[image]